# SwipeCellKit action won't perform segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue, swipe

I'm using SwipeCellKit for my TO DO List app. When the user swipes left it deletes the item, but when the user swipes right I want him to be able to set a reminder on this item, so I've created an action[set a reminder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfSL2.png)

this action should perform a segue which brings the user to a custom popup with a date picker in it. The problem is that when I click on the button to set a reminder the simulator quits with an uncaught exception. I've already tried to perform deletion from this button it works perfectly, I've also tried to perform another segue to another view controller from this button the simulator quits. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Here's my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {        if orientation == .left {
        guard isSwipeRightEnabled else { return nil }
        let setReminder = SwipeAction(style: .default, title: "Set a reminder") { action, indexPath in

           self.updateModelByAddingAReminder(at: indexPath)

        }
        setReminder.image = UIImage(named: "reminder-icon")
        return[setReminder]
    }else{

        let deleteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, indexPath in

           self.updateModel(at: indexPath)

        }
        // customize the action appearance
        deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "delete-icon")


       // return [setReminder, deleteAction]
        return [deleteAction]
    }
```

Comment: self.updateModelByAddingAReminder code?

Comment: sorry forgot to add:                                                                                               func updateModelByAddingAReminder(at indexpath: IndexPath){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToDatePickerPopup1", sender: self)
    }

Comment: Do ypu have this segue? Seems like problem in another place

Comment: Yes, I have it. I found out that the problem is: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. , which isn't quite clear because my popup isn't a table view controller it's a view controller, so I'm stuck.

Comment: I also tried to solve the problem programmatically instead of using the segue but it gives the same error:          let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let popup = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Popup")
        self.present(popup, animated: true)

Comment: You shoud look at  self.updateModelByAddingAReminder(at: indexPath), you should look at value. May be you try get invalid row. May be you try get row than table is gone while executing update model. You can send me project and I can help.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried to solve it myself but I just can't find the problem. Here's a link to my github if you could have a look I would really appreciate it: [link] https://github.com/anaviktoriv/My-Todo-List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found problem in your options for cell. 
From doc 
The built-in .destructive, and .destructiveAfterFill expansion styles are configured to automatically perform row deletion when the action handler is invoked (automatic fulfillment). 
And you need use destructive style for cell in editActionsForRowAt. Or use another options, for example

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsOptionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> SwipeTableOptions {
    var options = SwipeTableOptions()
    options.transitionStyle = .border

    if orientation == .left{
        //or none
        options.expansionStyle = .selection
    }else{
        options.expansionStyle = .destructive
    }

    return options
}
```

Hope it's help.